# I'm ubuntu newbie, need help. on Dell 5537

Tags: drivers, filesystem, dell

I just got a new Dell 5537 i7 laptop with Ubuntu pre-installation on it. It's my first time to use Ubuntu system. I know may be my questions hav been asked before but frankly I tried to look them up and still I don\t know how to put it right.

1. First of all I noticed that HDD folders and partitions are not as they are displayed on windows, that got me confused. But my main problem here is that I want the system files on a separate partition and my other data like movies, games,books and other files on another partition is it applicable?
2. I want to know how to find the correspondent to the device manager of windows ? cause I want to make sure that my VGA card driver is installed, because when I checked the system details I was written in front of Graphics : unknown.
3. Finally if you kindly refer me to any useful guides for users who switch from windows to Ubuntu, that would be great.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You're asking multiple questions which is against the site format.  Ask one question per actual question post, please.

Comment: Welcome to AU! It would be better if you don't post multiple unrelated issues as a single question. Please [edit] your question and remove all but one issue, and either post new questions about them or, especially in this case, look for similar existing questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the forum policies

Comment: While this is a SSD/HD version, the process is the same for a data partition on the same drive: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage And: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670 Link to Many references: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandLineResources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Ubuntu family.

1. The answer to the first question, by default you have only one big partition installed (with a small swap partition which acts as a RAM supplement and a small /boot partition where the bootloader is present). I would personally suggest all your files to be put in your default folders because that would help search things faster and make the experience better. But, if you want a separate partition, refer to *excerpts* from this guide I have made sometime ago. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4FvxI6SUvM
2. There is no GUI based device manager alternative in Ubuntu because it is not needed. However, if you want to check whether you have all the drivers installed, just hit the super (windows) key and search for "additional drivers". It should scan for any drivers that are not installed during the installation process.
3. Unfortunately, we lack in terms of introduction videos. I am currently trying to solve this problem. You can look at this video I have made which can give you a rudimentary idea of how to use Ubuntu. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5vU8Gz9UjA

Comment: Video instructions aren't that wide-spread in the Linux community, because they have some serious drawbacks like accessibility and not being searchable.

Answer (score 0):

1. The file system of Ubuntu is totally different from Windows.
   There is a root directory marked as /.
   All other directories come out of this /.
   All the partitions are held by root.One of these directories, supposedly a separate partition called /home is the place where your personal files are kept.

Programs and system configuration files are in other places. They aren't in your /home folder by default, so you don't have to bother with making system files and personal files separate - they are already separate.

2. Most drivers come pre-installed with Ubuntu. Also go to system settings - Software and Updates - Proprietary Drivers to check if any other drivers are necessary.
3. http://www.tuxradar.com/linuxstarterpack
   http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/index_main.html

Comment: You're welcome.Please pick one of the answers as a solution. It may be helpful in the future when some other people have the same questions as yours.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can place your other data files on a separate partition.
2. According to Google, your laptop has Intel HD Graphics 4400 graphics. The driver for this and other Intel integrated graphics is built-in in Ubuntu. In order to confirm that your laptop has Intel HD Graphics 4400 graphics, run this command from the terminal to show your graphics processor details:

   ```
   lspci -vvnn | grep VGA
   ```

   If your laptop has a separate graphics card, the above command will also show the details for that graphics card. If your laptop has a separate NVIDIA or AMD graphics card, the built-in Additional Drivers utility will show you the available drivers for it, and you can also show the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your hardware by running the following command:

   ```
   ubuntu-drivers devices
   ```
3. A good introductory guide to Ubuntu is the free PDF book: Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04 written by the Ubuntu Manual Team.

   - [Getting Started with Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads)
   - [Getting Started with Ubuntu 16.04](https://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/16.04/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2016.04.pdf)
4. The official Ubuntu documentation for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server is found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/).