# Dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15 on SSD and using HDD for storage

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, drive, windows-10

I'm looking for advice on how to create the following setup, if it is even possible at all:

I have a PC running Windows 10, which is installed onto my 120GB SSD (C:). I have also installed my most frequently used programs onto this drive. At present, 60GB of the total 109GB free is being used. I then also have a 1TB HDD installed which has been divided into two main partitions (D: and E:) of around 450+GB each. As of now, I use the D: partition for storage of all my files, documents, pictures etc. for Windows, as well as any other programs which I do not need running on the SSD. I have recently cleared the E: partition so this is completely empty.

My question is this - How can I set aside maybe 40-50GB on the C: drive to install Ubuntu and have it dual-boot alongside Windows using GRUB, as well as having space to install important Ubuntu programs on this SSD? I would then like to continue using the D: partition of the HDD as my storage for Windows, and then have my E: available for Ubuntu storage and any other Ubuntu programs which I do not need on the SSD.

Is all of this possible? My idea would be to go through the normal Ubuntu install form a disk, and create the EFI System Partition, `/` and swap (I have 8GB of RAM) partitions in the free space on the SSD, and then the `/home` partition on the E: drive. Can this be done without affecting or losing any of my Windows partitions and associated storage?

Here are images of my drives and partitions to be clear:

[image: Drives & available space]

[image: Partitions]

(By the way, this 1TB HDD failed a while ago under warranty, so it was sent away and returned with these 2 450GB partitions and the other few recovery and EFI partitions. The last 511MB EFI partition is for me installing Ubuntu onto the E: partition last night as a test run, which I now cannot seem to delete.)

Comment: You should only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. I normally install Ubuntu in 25GB / (root) partition with many applications I use 12 to 14GB of /. And of the / I include /home with .wine and Picasa using about 2GB. But all the rest of my data is in data partition on HDD. Grub will automatically install to sda's ESP, but that should not be an issue. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage

Comment: Cool - I am also looking for similar setup on my new Dell Laptop with SSD and HDD. Did you manage to get Dual Boot working with this setup? Would be nice if you keep updating this thread for others to benefit from in case of success (Y)