# Installing Ubuntu on SSD and sharing second HDD with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I currently have:

- SSD Disk (54.5 GB free of total 112)

  - Windows 10 installed here
  - I would like to install Primary Ubuntu here
- HDD Disk (172 GB free of total 465)

  - I would like to have Logical home here and access to Windows partition

Here I have one question:

1. Could you please tell me why is my HDD displayed as unknown in the Kubuntu installer? It's also unavailable for display, snapshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzfcp.jpg).

My Windows situation looks like in the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4VGs.png). Please take a look and let me know if my assumption are correct and if I should proceed with the steps.

Looking forward for your answers! :)

Regards,

Comment: 1. Probably it's because you have fastoboot enabled on Windows. You have to disable it. And reduce the partitions from windows, otherwise it will say that there are problems and no one knows what it will do then.

Comment: You can install the systems according to your plan. Just install Windows on the disk you want and Ubuntu after that.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the answers! I will try and let you know :)

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI boot mode on a gpt partitioned drive. If so make sure the HDD is also gpt partitioned. http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage

Comment: all working fine! writting from kubuntu:) thank you!