# Can /home/user/music and other media folders be moved to a separate drive?

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, directory

I have two hard drives. One is a 256GB SSD and the other is a 1TB HDD. I installed Ubuntu to the SSD and that is where my /home directory resides. I would like to use the HDD for media storage. How can I point /home/user/music (and ~/movies, ~/pictures, etc.) to the larger HHD but keep my /home directory on the smaller, faster SSD?

Comment: Using Linking, but similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best solution however it could be useful. You could create subfolder 'Media' for example and mount your 1TB HDD partition to ~/Media. So you'll get internal media storage in ~/Media that physically placed on your 1TB HDD. Couple good guides: [one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MoveMountpointHowto), [two](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/separatehome), [three](https://ubuntu.wordpress.com/2006/01/29/move-home-to-its-own-partition/).