# HDD+SSD Dualboot Setup Questions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, samsung

I have a Samsung Gaming Series Laptop that is about 3 years old running 16.04 that I tried to upgrade from 2 750GB HDDs to a 1.5 TB 5400 RPM HDD for Storage and a 500GB Samsung Evo 850.
I hit a brick wall here, and most of the info concerning SSDs is more than two years old.

Right now I have a running Ubuntu with partitions all over the place, each with their own mount point. `/home`, `/var` and `/tmp` are on HDD, root and `/usr` are on SSD. Windows is intalled fully on SSD, because I use it only for gaming (shame on me, but GTAV and Skyrim on Wine would be a pain).
While Windows boots in about 5 seconds, Ubuntu needs up to two minutes, which is not what I got a SSD for.

So which directories are save to put on the SSD?
Some say I should limit writes as much as I can, some say modern SSDs are fine with loads of writes. 
Now where should I put which partitions? 
Can I move /home to SSD? 
Maybe with links to a bigger HDD Folder for files that don't need to be on the SSD? 
Which steps should I take to optimize for performance and longevity?
And are there any things I should be super cautious about?

Comment: 2 minutes sounds like there's a different issue than a storage access bottleneck. That would be a long time even to boot from a rotating disk. You should look into creating a [boot chart](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/04/ubuntu-boot-chart-make-graph-with-your.html) and analysing that for stalling boot processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So which directories are save to put on the SSD?

Any directory you want on it. I would advice the whole system and store your private data on a partition on the HDD.

> Can I move /home to SSD?

Yes. I myself only put the directories in /home/$USER/ onto a partition. Since those directories are maintained from a config file (`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`) I keep a copy of that on the partition and on re-install copy it over the new one.

> Which steps should I take to optimize for performance and longevity?

All I would worry about is "tmpfs". I'd move those into RAM. And make sure "trim" is enabled/working.

> And are there any things I should be super cautious about?

I am prepared for the SSD to fail. And that preparation is: have an SSD in the cupboard still in its packaging, install the disk. Install Ubuntu on disk. Mount partitions. Copy `/discword/user-dirs.dirs` to `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Install some extra software.

Takes about 30 minutes in total.

Comment: I do similar to Rinzwind, but use links to map folders on ext4 /mnt/data partition on HDD, but only have / (root) on SSD including /home. But then /home only has the hidden files & folders. When I still had Windows I had two data partitions one NTFS for any data to share with windows and one ext4. http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage  And: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670 See post #4 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198