# How to mount individual directories in /home on separate drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have an Ubuntu install with my /home directory mounted on a HDD partition with the system / mounted on an ssd. However, I have certain programs (like Android Studio and IntelliJ) that I wish to keep under my specific user home account (under /home/me/) in the filesystem but actually stored on the SSD for speed improvements.

Is there a way to do this and place individual directories in a filesystem on a separate partition?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: This shows linking all the common folders in /home into a data partition. You can pick & choose or add other folders/partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage