# Mounting Partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount

I recently built a new PC and installed Ubuntu as my sole operating system. I have both an SSD drive and a 2T HDD drive.

So I've installed the OS on my SSD drive, and I've created a 1T partition on the HDD to store all my media files.

I'd like to mount /home on the HDD, but don't know how. When I use gparted as a live USB, the mount option under the partition menu is grayed out.

Additionally, the partitions on my SSD don't list any mount points. I'm trying to get my drives all sorted and organized, but I'm still new at this.

Here are some screen shots:

[image: SSD DRIVE PARTITIONS]

[image: HHD DRIVE PARTITIONS]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Easier to do when installing with SomethingTo move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
 Else. And partition in advance with gparted. Is sdb gpt partitioned? http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu I like to have additional / (root) partitions also on both drives. You can have the shared NTFS data drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Your partitions look good as they are. I'd move swap to HDD. What do you mean that you like to mount /home on the HDD? /home right now is on the SSD, and you've got plenty of room there. Please give more details about your goal.

Comment: hey there. how do you know /home is on the SSD? No mounts are listed...basically I just want to use the SSD for operating systems (Ubuntu now, might load Windows later as well) and then store all my data on the on an ntfs HDD. I've read that some people just put the root on the SSD and then put /home on HDD, I'm assuming for storage reasons. If I'm not making sense it's because I'm new at this.

Comment: /home is on SSD because you did a standard Ubuntu installation on the SSD, and that places / and /home there. If ultimately you wish to install Windows, and share data via a NTFS partition, that works well. Mount the NTFS partition in Ubuntu by editing `/etc/fstab`, then create Music/Pictures/Video/etc. folders on the NTFS partition, and place your data in those folders. You can always soft link those folders back to /home on your SSD if you wish. As I mentioned earlier, I would move swap to HDD.

Comment: Start new comments with `@heynnema` if you want to get my attention, or I may miss what you say.