# Installing on a machine that has Windows 10, and SSD and a hard drive

Tags: system-installation, ssd, windows-10

I'm installing Ubuntu on one of my own PCs for the first time. I just built this new rig and it has a 250GB SSD, and a 3TB regular hard drive. I also have Windows 10 installed on the SSD.

I would like to install Ubuntu on the SSD as well, but I'd like to use the hard drive to store files (which I'm currently doing on Windows as well). What's the best way to go about using both drives for both OSs?

Comment: You can free 20~30GB on the SSD for `/` plus a `/home` and `swap` on the HDD. Just a suggestion, there are many other possibilities.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: You can share data on large NTFS partition. NTFS shared on HDD
http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage But with Windows 10 you must have its fast start up off, which really is just hibernation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Is Windows installed in UEFI mode to gpt drive? http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu