# How to clone Ubuntu 16.04 partition from triple booted HDD to SSD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

Just got a new SSD. It's a Samsung EVO 750 (120 GB). It's MBR. I have 3 operating systems in my HDD (1 TB) which is GPT (and has a loooot of partitions). One is the pre-installed Windows that came along with my laptop, I use it only for Photoshop now. The other two are Linux OSes. I am trying to create partitions in the SSD to have Ubuntu installed in one and the other have some Windows apps that *need* an SSD, only those apps and not the OS itself.

Ubuntu has too many settings and configs which I can't afford to lose or create again. So my best option is to clone the Ubuntu partition to one of the SSD partitions and leave the other partition as an NTFS for Windows to access.

How do I go on about it? I have checked the internet, but I seem to be lost.

Comment: Do you have a separate /home? All your user settings are in /home? Only if you made system settings changes, those would be in /etc. I still suggest a new install to gpt drive preformatted using gpt since your system is UEFI and you should not try to convert to BIOS/MBR.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu And if two Linux installs better to share all data by having a /mnt/data partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage

Comment: I can do the Gparted part with `fdisk` as well, right? @oldfred

Comment: Only the very newest fdisk supports gpt drives, or versions in updated 16.04 or later. If wanting command line tool use gdisk or parted. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Answer (score 0):

clonezilla is an excellent disk/partition clone program.

get a live boot image here: http://clonezilla.org/

download the image and burn it to cd.boot from the cd.

the program has a grapfical inteface that guides you through it.

the cloned partition will have the same uuid as the original,
so log into ubuntu and use gparted to generate a new uuid for the clone.

last update grub to get the new ubuntu added to the menu.

Comment: Please elaborate the steps. :D