# Ubuntu won't allow me to merge two partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted, home-directory

I must admit I am a noob at computers, but I somehow managed to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. But, during the process, I messed up the partitions. How can I merge F and /home?

Here's the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH9eg.png).

Thanx a bunch and sorry if the answer is obvious.

Comment: You can grow or shrink partitions, but not merge them to my knowledge. If the partitions were next to each other you could delete one and grow the other, but in your case you'd have to delete one, move the partition in the middle towards the end of the disk (so space is next to your other one) then grow it.   `gparted` is the tool I'd use for this, but I'd boot a live/install disk and do it from there (so /home isn't mounted)

Comment: Another alternative is to just mount it as another data directory. I use /mnt/data. And link folders into /home, so it does not matter that it is another partition. One example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage Or you can move /home to larger partition: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 2):

The partition '/dev/sda8' which you refer to as 'F' would need to be emptied, and deleted, moved adjacent to the '/home' partition and then have '/home' expanded into it.  Do accomplish all of this, you will need to have a liveUSB to boot from, as you will be moving the '/' (root) partition during the process.  In order, the steps would be:

1. Boot into your regular Ubuntu session.
2. Using the file manager, navigate to /media/picard/18..... (I'm not going to type the full name)
3. Copy all files that you want to retain from this partition, to someplace in your '/home' directories
4. Boot using the liveUSB
5. Start gparted from the liveUSB
6. Delete the partition '/dev/sda8'
7. Move the partition '/dev/sda5' as far to the right as possible.  This will place the unpartitioned space next to your home partition, and will take some time to finish.
8. Expand your home partition to include the unpartitioned space.
9. Reboot your computer, booting from the hard disk into Ubuntu
10. After rebooting (which may take longer than normal) examine your file '/etc/fstab' using the command `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.  If you see a line mounting a partition into '/media/picard/18...' place a `#` at the beginning of the line, and save the file by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>