# Install Ubuntu on SSD on Acer Laptop

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a Acer Aspire E15-512-C0GA laptop

I am changing the HDD to an 256GB SSD.

is there anything special that I need to do while installing ubuntu 18.04?

thank very much and appreciate all your support

Vik

Comment: Acer has a unique requirement of setting "trust" once installed to allow UEFI boot. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

If you are just install a fresh installation on the SSD there isn't anything critical for a beginner user. There is some optimisation you can perorm if you are a serious user (I haven't bothered), and [instructions can be found on easy linux tips](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/ssd.html).

If you are planning on using both the SSD and the HDD then you may want to set the home directory to the HDD. Plenty of examples of how to do this, here is one AskUbutu post [Dual Boot with SSD and HDD Storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage?rq=1)