How do I mount another partition on startup as myself?
I am on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I'm currently dual booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu, and I have many symlinks in Ubuntu that lead to things in my Windows partition. It's quite annoying to have to manually mount the partition every time I turn on my PC, so I started attempting to make it do it on boot.
I have tried editing /etc/fstab, using the GNOME Disks tool, adding a startup command, but none of it is working. They are all mounting the partition on startup, but it makes it more of a hassle than before, because the symlinks still do not function, and when I try to do anything with the partition in Nautilus, it makes me enter my password, saying "Authentication is required to (the action I'm doing) T-FORCE TM8FFW002T (/dev/nvme0n1p3) mounted by another user".
How do I make it mount on startup as my own user?

Who owns the mountpoint?

use the disks utility to edit the mount point, select mount at startup and other mount options, reboot to test that is the partition is mounted at startup,  recreat the symlinks based  on the mount point.

Disks defaults are not very good and worse for NTFS partitions, NTFS example fstab entry - TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493845 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2499276 Best not to mount Windows c: drive partition, but use a shared data partition. Windows fast startup, bitlocker must be off and no chkdsk required for Linux NTFS driver to work.

@OrganicMarble I am not sure what you mean by that. I'm the only one who uses this PC, so I guess me? I just assumed it was the system taking ownership of the mount, because it's the system running the command at startup. Sorry if I come across as dense or something, I literally started using Linux for the first time less than a week ago.

@guiverc Sorry about that. I'm new to the whole Linux thing. What exactly are you looking for? I don't really understand what your comment is asking me. I can share some information here or update my post if you'd like though.

@oldfred The thing is, it works fine when I don't attempt to mount on startup. If I just open the partition in Nautilus normally without doing any of the startup stuff, it lets me in and it mounts itself, making my symlinks work. So I'm pretty sure it's not my Windows settings, I think I'm just messing something up on the Ubuntu side of things. I already have all the mentioned Windows settings turned off.

@TalaatEtman That was the first thing I tried. It does not affect anything. it just doesn't mount at startup despite my changes.

what is the mount point for the partition when you open it normally?

When you open with gui it usually uses udisks or udisks2 or maybe now udiskctl which does have better default settings than those used by Disks. Default mount point then is /media/$USER/UUID. Better to add labels so default mount is by label not UUID. $USER is your login name. But may be shown as 1000 as first user in system is 1000.

@TalaatEtman The mount point when I open it from the GUI is "/mount/theswagninja49/Windows". I tried setting this same mount point when using Gnome Disks, manually setting it in the fstab file, and adding a startup command. All had the same issue listed in the post.

@oldfred So what exactly are you suggesting I do to fix the issue? The information is useful, but I don't understand what exactly you want me to do with it.

See my first comment with links to examples on fstab entries if you want permanent mounting with fstab. If you do not mount to same place then you will have to update links. But you should always create mount then add symlinks. https://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage


because the symlinks still do not function

This is likely because the methods you tried all mounted the partition on a different mountpoint than the mountpoint used by Nautilus when mounting the disk, which is the mountpoint your symlinks try to access (or the mountpoint is right but the filesystem has been mounted without allowing access to your user).

when I try to do anything with the partition in Nautilus, it makes me enter my password, saying "Authentication is required to (the action I'm doing) T-FORCE TM8FFW002T (/dev/nvme0n1p3) mounted by another user"

This sounds more like the mountpoint is right but the filesystem has been mounted without allowing access to your user.
First, do a cleanup of all the auto-mounting things you set in place.
Then unomunt the partition, and to simulate mounting from Nautilus, which will allow access to your user, use this udisksctl command:
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/nvme0n1p3

If your symlinks start working, setup GNOME to run the command on startup (you seem to know how to do that already).

This worked flawlessly! I think the command I was putting in before was for an older version of Ubuntu or something, because I'm not sure why it didn't work. Thanks!

@TheSwagNinja49 You're welcome!
