# Clone Only Ubuntu from dual boot 1TB HDD to new 240GB SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I have A Lenovo g50-80 80e5 with 1TB HDD and 12 GB RAM. The HDD contains a dual boot setup (Win 10 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), the details of which you can see in the attached screenshots.

I want to move to a new SSD of 240GB size and want to clone just the Ubuntu partitions.

As you can see in the screenshots I have separate `/` (root) and `/home` (home) partitions.

I have read the solutions in the questions in this forum about this at the below links:

1. [Clone Linux Partition Only from Dual Boot 16.04 disk to make new Bootable Linux disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997789/clone-linux-partition-only-from-dual-boot-16-04-disk-to-make-new-bootable-linux)
2. [Cloning a dual boot system from HDD to SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222193/cloning-a-dual-boot-system-from-hdd-to-ssd)

What I am concerned is that, if I do a per partition clone of the `/` (root) and `/home` (home) partitions, I still need to clone the `/boot/efi` also.

The thing is that I don't have a clue about it. Will cloning all three partitions with exact partition type and size be enough to make a bootable resultant SSD?

What else should I do ?

I dont care about the windows boot to be honest. but it would be nice to have it (if possible on the new SSD itself).

Please suggest you thoughts.

---

GParted:

[image: gparted screenshot]

`sudo parted /dev/sda`:

[image: sudo parted /dev/sda result screenshot]

`sudo fdisk -l`:

[image: sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda result screenshot]

`sudo blkid`:

[image: sudo blkid | grep /dev/sda result screenshot]